# Как убрать диалоговое окно вызываемое из библиотеки?

Tags: c#, dll

Своё приложение пишу на С#. Имеется устройство подключаемое по USB. Для общения с устройством используется нативная библиотека. В случае если устройство не подключено в USB, то при вызове функции `int Connect()`, для подключения устройства, вылезает диалоговое окно с сообщением что устройство не обнаружено и 2 кнопочки "Повторить" и "Отмена". Если нажать "Отмена", то в программе возвращается код ошибки, который можно обработать, как мне нужно.

Единственной проблемой является само диалоговое окно - хочется его избежать таким образом, чтобы оно не вылазило или по умолчанию, автоматически, нажималась "Отмена".

Есть варианты получить желаемый результат?

Comment: а что за нативная библиотека имеется ввиду?

Comment: ну а посмотреть какой метод выполняется при нажатии кнопки "отмена" вы можете?

Comment: *вылезает диалоговое окно с сообщением что устройство не обноружено и 2 кнопочки "Повнорить" и "Отмена"* Первейший вопрос - чьё окно? библиотеки или операционной системы? Если первое - читайте документацию, в приличной библиотеке должно быть нечто, позволяющее работать библиотеке в немом режиме, без интерактивного взаимодействия с пользователем - какое-нить свойство или типа того...

Comment: @mymedia, не имеет значения.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, библиотека не моя, она от производителя устройства. Как я посмотрю какой метод вызывается при нажатии "Отмена"?

Comment: @Akina, обычное диалоговое окно которое вызывается внутри библиотеки. В документации всё скудно. Первым делом просмотрел все доступные методы. Если бы нашел что-то подходящее, то даже не писал сюда. Настройка "немого" режима отсутствует в данной библиотеке.

Comment: *Первым делом просмотрел все доступные методы.* Я бы скорее предположил, что переключением в тихий режим рулит некое свойство. Попробуйте получить полный список того, что экспортирует библиотека, и там покопаться. *библиотека не моя, она от производителя устройства* И что, у производителя нет вменяемой техподдержки, с которой можно пообщаться?

Comment: @Akina не нашёл таких свойств. Тех.поддержки нету, они не отвечают на письмо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как было сказано в комментариях, поищите возможность управления окном в подключаемой библиотеке.
Если возможности управления этим окном нет, можете воспользоваться методами доступными в библиотеки windows - user32.dll. Для этого импортируйте 3 функции:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);   
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string className, string title);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, string text);
```

Используя программу Spy++ получите данные диалогового окна и кнопки (имя класса и имя окна(опционально)).
Напишите метод, который будет нажимать кнопку - отмена, вроде:

```
    public static void PushCancel()
    {
        int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        var hwnd = FindWindow("Имя класса", "Имя окна, если нет - null");
        var hwndChild = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Отмена");
        SendMessage(hwndChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, null);
        SendMessage(hwndChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, null);
    }
```

Если вызываемый метод (int Connect()) блокирует выполнение основного потока, зациклите этот метод и вызывайте через определённые промежутки времени в другом потоке.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!
Однако, можете подсказать следующее: имя класса в программе spy++ отображено как "#32770 (Диалоговое окно)" прямо так и указать в функции `FindWindow("#32770 (Диалоговое окно)", "Connection Error")`?

Comment: @GoodSimon имя класса это весь текст, который находится в поле Class Name в Spy++ (моем случае было так)